# Cypress unable to find selector - React/CSS Modules/Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, css-modules

I am writing e-2-e tests for our frontend using Cypress.

When I try to target an element, I am using `.button-module_btnLabel__30kQb`, but as I understand this makes my test brittle as the classname hash may change.

However, when I try to add a selector, Cypress can't find it. An example below:

```
import { Button } from '...ui'
```

```
      <Button.Primary
        data-cy="submit"
        onClick={startLogin}
      >
        Log In
      </Button.Primary>
```

```
      cy.get('data-cy="submit"')
      .should('be.visible')
      .should('contain.text','Log In')
      .click()
```

```
     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `[data-cy=submit]`, but never found it.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting on an attribute, you need enclosing square brackets.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="submit"]')
```

Note React does not pass on all attributes, but `data` prefix should be ok.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding square brackets, results in the same error:

```cy.get('[data-cy="submit"]')```

```AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `[data-cy="submit"]`, but never found it.```

Are there any alternative methods to selecting? For example, can I search for the first part of the button ? How my button currently looks:

```cy.get('.button-module_btnLabel__30kQb')```

Comment: I had the same initially. After changing the value to "submit1" in case there was a reserved-word problem going on, it worked and stayed working after changing back to "submit". Best guess it was something to do with hot-module reload, but I could see the correct attribute in the dev-tools, so not sure why.